# Как мне добавить в этот код кнопки вместо команд?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

делаю бота в тг, этот код работает, но я хочу чтобы вместо команд "balance""click" были клавиатурные кнопки, а вывод был инлайновской,когда нажимаешь на "баланс" то выводился твой баланс и ниже инлайн кнопка вывод. я пытался их всячиски их добавить, но увы все время ошибки. Не знаю как правильно их сюда добавить. буду очень благодарен с этим вопросом. Вот сам код:

````
import sqlite3
from telegram import Update
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import CallbackQueryHandler 




bot = telebot.TeleBot('*******')
TOKEN = "********"
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher




conn = sqlite3.connect('balances.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS balances(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, balance REAL)''')
conn.commit()




MIN_WITHDRAWAL_AMOUNT = 5




@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(update: Update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM balances WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    if user:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM balances WHERE user_id=?', (update.message.from_user.id,))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        update.message.reply_text('Выберите действие:')
    else:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO balances VALUES (?, 0)", (user_id,))
        conn.commit()
        update.message.reply_text("ты пис")




def link_click(update: Update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM balances WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()    
    if user:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE balances SET balance=balance+1 WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
        conn.commit()
        update.message.reply_text("Баланс успешно увеличен")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Вы не зарегистрированы")





def withdraw(update: Update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM balances WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()      
    if user:
        balance = user[1]
        



        if balance >= MIN_WITHDRAWAL_AMOUNT:
            bot.send_message(chat_id='*******', text=f'Пользователь {user_id} запросил {balance} вывод средств')
            cursor.execute("UPDATE balances SET balance=balance-? WHERE user_id=?", (balance, user_id))
            conn.commit()
            update.message.reply_text("Запрос на вывод средств отправлен")
        else:
            update.message.reply_text("Недостаточно средств для вывода")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Вы не зарегистрированы")




def balance(update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM balances WHERE user_id=?', (user_id,))
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    if user:
        balance = user[1]
        update.message.reply_text(f'Баланс: {balance}')
    else:
        update.message.reply_text('Вы не зарегистрированы в базе данных')




updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('click', link_click))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('withdraw', withdraw))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('balance', balance))




updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()```
````